# Show all labels of a post using javascript in Blogger XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

I have this part of code which belongs to a js file from a site (google blog) I am working on.

```
function labelset(e) {
    var a = e.entry,
        t = a.category[0].term;
    document.write('<div class="post-cat"><a href="/search/label/' + t + '">' + t + "</a></div>")
};
```

With this function, user gets a "flying" `div` over every post in index page, that shows the relevant label for every post. My problem is that in case that a post has more than one label, this function shows-up only the first label `alphabetically`!!! Any idea how can I get them all?

Comment: Why you can't use standart Blogger tags?

<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
  <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <a expr:href='data:label.url' expr:title='data:postLabelsLabel' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a>
  </b:if>
  <b:if cond='data:label.isLast'><b:else/>,</b:if>
</b:loop>
</b:if>

Comment: Because this is how current template works and I don't have the permission to change it... :( But thank you very much for your example!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following script which shows all post titles with all its corresponding labels.. for ease of understanding I've made every variable self explanatory.. it works perfect in blogger..

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function LoadDetails(TotalFeed) {
 var PostTitles = new Array();
 var PostURLs = new Array();
 var PostLabels=new Array();
 var d="";
 if ("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) {
 var PostEntries = TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
 for (var PostNum = 0; PostNum < PostEntries; PostNum++) {
  var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
  PostTitles.push(ThisPost.title.$t);
  d="";
 if("category"in TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum])
 {
 for(var b=0;b<TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum].category.length;b++)
  d+='<a href="/search/label/'+TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum].category[b].term+'?max-results=8">'+TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum].category[b].term+"</a> \u002C "; 
  b=d.lastIndexOf(" \u002C ");-1!=b&&(d=d.substring(0,b))
 }
  
  var ThisPostURL;
  for (var LinkNum = 0; LinkNum < ThisPost.link.length; LinkNum++) {
   if (ThisPost.link[LinkNum].rel == "alternate") {
   ThisPostURL = ThisPost.link[LinkNum].href;
   break;
   }
  }
  PostURLs.push(ThisPostURL);
  PostLabels.push(d);
 }
 }
 DisplayPosts(PostTitles, PostURLs, PostLabels);
}

function DisplayPosts(PostTitles, PostURLs, PostLabels) {
 var NumberOfEntries = PostTitles.length;
 document.write('<ul class="blogger-archive">');
 for (var EntryNum = 0; EntryNum < NumberOfEntries; EntryNum++) {
  document.write('<li><a href ="' + PostURLs[EntryNum] + '">' + PostTitles[EntryNum] + "</a> | <span>"+PostLabels[EntryNum]+"</span></li>");
 }
document.write('</ul>');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default?max-results=500&alt=json-in-script&callback=LoadDetails"></script>
```

*In your case it should be something like this..

```
function labelset(e) { //Note:- e must be TotalFeed.feed
var a = e.entry;
for(var b=0;b<a.category.length,b++){
    document.write('<div class="post-cat"><a href="/search/label/' + a.category[b].term + '">' + a.category[b].term + "</a></div>");
}};
```

Hope this helps..